# How to get Rich Snippet results using Custom Search

Tags: rich-snippets

The following query in Google returns the price of the product:

site:elcorteingles.es "4242005059898"

[See screenshot of the query in Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x5YA.png)

When I make the query through Custom Search the **price** is not shown in the results.